# 404 not found after docker-compose build app

Tags: laravel, docker, ubuntu, nginx, docker-compose

I am not even developer , more of just IT Project Manager, but since I am quiet young and my boss forced me to deploy the latest releases on our server , the only way I found it easiest for the moment is to do it manually. So after I installed docker , docker-compose , laravel , nginx and all needed updates and don't receive any error messages in Ubuntu 22.04 , whenever I visit the page (the name of it is IP address of my server and :80), I continiously see on my  page "404 not found" error , under which there is described the version of my Nginx. I've proceeded with all kinds of troubleshooting , but nothing helped. Also I've uploaded my project manually , to the /var/www/ directory as the root in my configs needed.
SOS!

I've literally checked-up everything ,and yet nothing helped me at all . I just need to deploy succesfully the files on server of our project.

Comment: Well, if you see the nginx at the bottom of the page, then it is an NGINX 404, so you do not have the site config correctly configured, that is why 404... You need to share the config and where you are putting the project files (path)

Comment: It's not on the bottom of the page but just under 404 not found error message on page, on top, the direction I needed to put in the project file was /var/www/public

Comment: and do you have the project inside `www` so you end up having the `public` folder in `/var/www/public` or do you have all the project files inside `public`?

Comment: Yes , you are totally right , I end up with “public” folder as well , but all my project files are in “www”

Comment: Also I’ve tried to insert all my project files to “public”folder , but it did not work as well

Comment: Read this part of the documentation, it should help you understand more how to deploy it: https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/deployment#introduction

Comment: Thanks , I’ve just did reset my server and did everything from the very beginning

Comment: You have nginx, so your 'deployed sites' are in `sites-available` of your server (most likely docker). There should be .conf files in there, check your .conf file for your site, the `root` directive, for a Laravel project should point to its public directory